# capture output from a pipe and store it in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdin

I am trying to capture output from a pipe and store it in a variable. Using a subshell ie var=$(computeOutput) WILL NOT WORK because the computeOutput function itself is setting other variables that need to be stored in the same scope as the output. If I use a subshell the other variables will be set in the subshell's local copy but not in the parent shell.

One solution I thought of is the following:

Given the function...

function storeOutput() {
  var=$(cat)
}

...when I do the following...

echo "hello" | storeOutput; echo $var

... "hello", the value of var, is printed on the console

However when I use this function from inside a script instead of getting the correct result I get a listing of the contents of the current directory. FYI I am using mac OSX with mac ports installed.

Can anyone explain why this is happening??? OR BETTER STILL SUGGEST ANOTHER SOLUTION

Comment: Its not really clear what `var=$(cat)` is supposed todo. You should post the simplified code as is insteand providing a non functionnal example.

Comment: Remember that if you do not supply arguments to cat it takes std-in and passes that data to std-out. The sub-shell inherits the std-in from the parent shell in the expression $(cat) and the result is interpreted as text by the parent shell thanks to the "$". That text is then used in the right hand side of the assignment var=$(cat). Its a way of capturing the output from the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: In the script I was piping multi-line output to the storeOutput function. When I printed the value of var I forgot to enclose it in double quotes, ie "$var" so assume it regarded part of the output as a command, such as ls

Other than that the function storeOutput() { var=$(cat) } seems to work